# move form when panel is clicked vb.net

Tags: vb.net, panel

I have a form1 with none border-style & I want to make this form moving when the user moves panel1.
after making the simple search is stack over I found the same case with this solution C#

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    this.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + e.X , Cursor.Position.Y + e.Y);
}
}
```

for my case I use vb.net, so I try to make similar code but I failed :

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GunaPanel1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MainDashboard.Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X + e.X, Cursor.Position.Y + e.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where are you failing? use c# to vb converter

Comment: when i convert it to vb.net it doesnt work

Comment: what is MainDashboard? is it form name?

Comment: yes this is my form name

Comment: this is current form name where panel is located?

Comment: no its form name when the panel located

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution :
MouseIsDown and MouseIsDownLoc  is module level variables.

```
    Private MouseIsDown As Boolean = False
    Private MouseIsDownLoc As Point = Nothing
    Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            If MouseIsDown = False Then
                MouseIsDown = True
                MouseIsDownLoc = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            End If

            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + e.X - MouseIsDownLoc.X, Me.Location.Y + e.Y - MouseIsDownLoc.Y)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
        MouseIsDown = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: yes, I tried this before it doesn't work because when you hold on the panel and move the form will disappear & appear multiple times

Comment: Do you want to move panel on that form? If yes change Me with Panel1.

Comment: actually i want to move form not panel

Comment: Do you mean when user press left button on panel and move panel then form should move and panel position will remain same with respect to form ?